# Kendo grid checkbox get last selected value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid with a select option. My question is how do I get `ProductName` from the last selected row? Example like [this](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/checkbox-selection-dataitem-last-selected-row). I have tried with this but `row` is null. Appreciate your help.

[FULL DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/IduGAfAr)

```js
function onChange(e) {
    var rows = e.sender.select();
    rows.each(function(e) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var row = $(e.target).closest("tr"); //<-- this value capture null
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
        var productName = dataItem.ProductName;
        alert(productName);
   })
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect parameters in the function in `each`.

This causes name masking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages)#Name_masking

At the outer level, you have:

```
function onChange(e) {
```

Then, in the third line, you have:

```
 rows.each(function(e) {
```

That's two functions of `e`. So which `e` counts? The inner one *masks* the outer one.

The correct arguments for the inner function are:

```
rows.each(function(index, row) {
```

Now, you're already iterating over rows, so you have the row, you don't need to look for it with any `closest()`.

You also have the grid, it's `e.sender`, because you're in a grid event.

That gives you the following code:

```
function onChange(e) {
    var rows = e.sender.select();
    rows.each(function(index, row) {
        console.log(row);
        var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);
        console.log(dataItem);
        var productName = dataItem.ProductName;
        console.log(productName);
   })           
};
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/IKoLEGuF)

In the future, be wary of the difference between Kendo events and jQuery events.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `grid.select()` inside grids `change` function:

```
function onChange(e) {
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
  console.log(selectedItem.ProductName)
};
```

Example: [Get last selected item](https://dojo.telerik.com/apIgEzaF)